# Vertex/face visibility given possible self-occlusion, python

Tags: python, opengl, geometry, render

I have a `.obj` file specifying 3D vertex locations and corresponding faces, along with a projection matrix. I'm looking for a fast way of determining which vertices/faces are visible and which are occluded. I've looked into openGL, but most tutorials I'm looking at focus on full-blown rendering, and I'm not sure which direction I should be searching in.

Would love a solution using python, but happy to take a native openGL solution and wrap it/port from a different language :).

Comment: OpenGL already does face culling if enabled. Are you referring to/searching for something else?

Comment: My understanding from a quick read is that this removes faces facing the wrong way. That's a good start, but from what I understand it won't remove faces occluded by other parts of the object.